# DATA no displaying on print_r array

Tags: php

I cannot seem to find the issue for my code:

```
class Product {
public function fetch_all() {
    global $pdo;

    $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM products");
    $query->execute();

    return $query->fetchAll();
   }
}
$product = new Product;
$products = $product->fetch_all();
```

I use the print_r method to print all the data from $products but all it shows is ARRAY no database errors seem to appear or bugs can you.

Comment: This may sound dumb, but do you have any records on that table?

Comment: There is no `print_r` anywhere in your code.

Comment: Global references are the devil.

Comment: I don't show the print r here but yes i do have one and yes i do have data on my tables

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and back on again? Or just leaving it off ...

Comment: Top tip: if you are asking about a specific problem it just may be useful if you actually share said problem code.

Comment: @PeeHaa Do you have any better code for this kind of function?

Comment: Jay deleted his answer, which theoretically was correct. *"The `fetchAll()` in the function is returning an object. All that is left to do is -

`var_dump($products);`"* - I've tested this along with your "posted" code, and it worked well. You're obviously not doing something right and you should post full code. You're one vote away from the question being closed. What I think is happening, is that you're trying to do a `foreach($products as $var)` thus returning ARRAY.

Comment: I have undeleted,I wanted to double check by testing first @Fred-ii- and I, like you, was able to successfully test this.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Well, that's what I'm thinking, is that the OP is *probably* trying to do a `foreach` and isn't telling us. Or, it could be something else, and we've no idea because we're not there, behind "their" computer. Testing takes the guesswork out of things ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fetchAll()` in the function is returning an object. All that is left to do is -

```
var_dump($products);
```

You should also implement [PDO Error Checking](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php)

Comment: All it does is show me Produced Object ()

Comment: @JayBlanchard I take it you may have seen my comment to the OP? Edit: Ah, you have.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to test first @Fred-ii- - got interrupted by a phone call, then tested and confirmed. Now I have to go to a planning meeting where I'll teach the benefits of node.js for project I am consulting on ;-)

Comment: @JayBlanchard Enjoy Jay, *cheers*

Comment: @JayBlanchard TBH, I don't know how to test it any further doing a `foreach` instead of `print_r()`. So, I guess I'll just have to better my skills and off to Google I go lol

Comment: Hahahahaha @Fred-ii- I wouldn't! Especially given the lack of code provided. Besides, I just consider a `foreach` an extended `print_r` ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @JayBlanchard I know. This is just for my own personal skills knowledge. Edit: Never mind, I figured it out. It was so simple. Google, how I love thee lol - Edit #2: Will you lookah dat, answer accepted.